# Can we have a printable version of Q&A?

Tags: feature-request

I created a LibreOffice file to print [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/641). I'd like to upload the file for the community, but it would be even better to have a way of printing the answer without having to print the whole web page.

Comment: For an individual case, making a publicly viewable google doc might be the most straightforward way to host it.

Comment: Save a tree, and just make it as a favourite (the star thing). That way you always have the latest version in your "cook book"

Answer (score 1):

Found it on [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=21068&service=cooking.stackexchange). Not ideal, but workable and no syncing problems.

Comment: Very 'meta' that your comment about printing the answer appears at the bottom of the print out. :D

Comment: @yossarian, there's recursion going on all around us